# How to share Core Data between one ViewController to another controller (widget)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to save data at viewcontroller.swift, and fetch data at widget.swift

But I don't know how to access core data in widget.

How can I access/Fetch core data in widget?

Here is my code:

in viewController.swift

```
var container: NSPersistentContainer!
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
self.container = appDelegate.persistentContainer

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Entity", in: context)

if let entity = entity {
    let myentity = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    myentity.setValue("my name", forKey: "name")
}
```

in widget.swift

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    
    let containerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: <myGroupID>)!
    let storeURL = containerURL.appendingPathComponent("DataModel.sqlite")
    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Entity")
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
    container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
        } }
    
    
    let moc = CoreDataStack.shared.managedObjectContext
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "attribute1 == %@", "test")
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: "Entity")
    let result = try? moc.fetch(request)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this "context" global

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

First create NSManagedObject subclass:

Step 1:

**YourEntity+CoreDataClass.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

public class YourEntity: NSManagedObject {

}
```

**YourEntity+CoreDataProperties.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension YourEntity {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<YourEntity> {
        return NSFetchRequest<YourEntity>(entityName: "YourEntity")
    }

    @NSManaged public var attribute1: String?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?

}
```

Step 2: Save data in YourEntity
(I think you are storing it properly)

Step 3: Fetching data from YourEntity

You can fetch data from anywhere(in widget.swift)

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping ([YourEntity]) -> ()) {
        var yourResult : [YourEntity]?
        let request: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "YourEntity")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "attribute1 == %@", "test")
        do {
            yourResult = try context.fetch(request) as? [YourEntity]
            completion(yourResult)
        } catch let error as NSError{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!! but i have a 1question while following your answer. 

In widget.swift    yourResult = try context.fetch(request) as? [YourEntity]   generates error. 

error is `Value of type 'Provider.Context' (aka 'TimelineProviderContext') has no member 'fetch'.`  

I assume that context in viewcontroller.swift and context in widget is different. 

how can i get the right context??
(I'm sorry my English is not good)

Comment: Edited answer, check now.